# SQLite for BlackBerry

Tags: database, sqlite, blackberry, java-me

Is SQLite available for BlackBerry ?

Is any other Database option available other than SQLite ?

Answer (score 5):

SQLite has been shipped in Blackberry 5.0; here is the link: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/8682/SQLite_overview_701956_11.jsp

Answer (score 3):

SQLite is scheduled to be released in the next version of the BlackBerry device software, no idea when that will be.  Think they were scheduled to announce at hte recent WES event.

You could try using [Sybase SQL Anwhere](http://www.sybase.com/products/databasemanagement/sqlanywhere/blackberry) as it's available for Blackberry.

Comment: At WES 2009 they announced 5.0 (which will include support for SQLite) will be released in the fall of 2009.

Comment: I wouldn't trust SQL Anywhere.  The team I'm on couldn't get it to work properly, and the demo app crashed with Sybase demoed it to us.

Comment: So you vote me down for a 2 year old question that was applicable at the time but isn't now?

Answer (score 2):

SQLite is available as of BlackBerry OS version 5.0. Here's the link for more information:

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/8682/SQLite_overview_701956_11.jsp

Please be aware that there are a couple of things you have to watch out for when using SQLite in BlackBerry development. One is that there is a known issue when writing a SQLite to internal memory of certain devices (ie; Bold 9700 series).

In terms of other options for databases on the BlackBerry, no. At least none that I'm aware of. You have to use SQLite. This isn't necessarily a problem as SQLite is efficient and has a small memory footprint.

In terms of other methods of storage, you could use the Persistent Store. This can be a little tricky, but you could use a Vector object to organize how you are storing data.

Answer (score 1):

As stated before:
"SQLite has been shipped in Blackberry 5.0; here is the link: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/8682/SQLite_overview_701956_11.jsp"

but SQLite is also available in the WebWorks SDK.
See: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/webworks/api/Database.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Persistent Store for storing data in a Blackberry Application

see this [Persistent data storage](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11938/Persistent_data_storage_509562_11.jsp)

Answer (score 0):

I simply use txt files, it is a lot more complicated but the problem is some phones require a a memory card and others don't in order to use SQLite DB and the developers cant control whether the subscribers have a memory card or not.

Comment: How do text files act as a database?

Answer (score -2):

UltraliteJ is paid version for SQLite.

Comment: Many forums say Sqlite soon to be launched for Blackberry...Any idea  when it is going to be launched?

Comment: No, it's not.  It's a version of one of SQLite's proprietary rivals, SQL Anywhere (by Sybase).

Comment: Yeah!
So no chance to built a database like SqLite on Blackberry phones?

Comment: There obviously /is/ a chance, as seen by the blog post linked above and other posts elsewhere.  But so far, it's vaporware.

Comment: That's a different question entirely, and the answer is not obvious (unless you want to pay for proprietary SQL Anywhere).

Comment: i m looking for an open source option so is there any other option available for me .