# Is it possible to implement a lightweight database using Blackberry Persistance options?

Tags: blackberry, data-persistence

First I would like to explain why I want to use alternate Blackberry Persistance options rather than a Blackberry database itself, say SQLite. The reason is that the application i'm designing, I want it to be used in all the previous versions of Blackberry rather than just the ones having OS 5.0 or greater.

Now, coming back to the actual question, I have got a database that I want to replicate to be used in the Blackberry application. The database has 8 tables and each table has approximately 12 different columns. One of the table has 1000 rows. Now if I was to implement this DB for a Blackberry application , keeping in mind that it will work on all the versions of Blackberry, what would be the best way to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this pos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847292/sqlite-for-blackberry)t for some DB alternatives that would work pre-5.0, such as [SQL Anywhere for BlackBerry](http://www.sybase.com/products/databasemanagement/sqlanywhere/blackberry)

Comment: Dear Marc,
Thanks for the SQL Anywhere link. I must say I am relieved to know that there were SQL DBs prior to OS 5.0. But I note that in the System Requirements its stated that this DB is supported by OS 4.1 or later. Now my confusion still is, how do I implement a DB that would run with no problems what so ever with all the previous versions of Blackberry? or is it a target too big and just not possible? Plus, if I may ask, what would be your choice of a DB if you were to implement what I intend to implement.
Thanks.

Comment: Targetting 4.1 and later will get you 99.9% of the devices out there, so if you choose that as your base version you should be okay.  Realistically, 4.2.2 or 4.3 are also sufficient for the majority of devices out there.

Comment: Thank you Marc, that's exactly what I wanted to know.
Much Obliged.

Comment: PS. Here's a comprehensive list of popular OS for anyone trying to find out the answer to the same question as above
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry_OS

Comment: Great link, Tobias.  Another thing to consider too is that even though 4.5 may be available for a device, the end user may either not care to update (or maybe they don't know how) or in some cases if they're a corporate user on BES, the admins have locked down OS upgrades so that they have control over the process.  This can leave some people stuck on 4.2.2 (for example) on a 8330 even with 4.5 is available!